# Extract hour and minute from date function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date

I want to pass the time variable extracted from the database as a Date function in jQuery and want to extract hours and minutes from it and want to store it in a javascript variable.

```
var time="<?php echo $row['time']; ?>";
var time=new Date(time);
var hrs=time.getHours();
var min=time.getMinutes();
```

Please find if there is any error in this code.

Comment: Why dont you output the desired result either before in PhP or even more before in SQL/the database?

Comment: How is your ```$row['time']``` stored in DB? Is it in ***UNIX Timestamp*** or is it normal in the gregorian calendar format?

Comment: Its a timestamp

Comment: Okay, then read these answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/60220023/11926970 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/11926970

Answer (score 0):

You could find answers for this all over Stackoverflow or read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the date object.

However, here is an answer you might like

```
var myMinutes = 1; // This represent 1 minute subtraction
var myHours   = 60; // This represent 60 minutes subtraction which is 1 hour
var dateMSubObject= new Date(oldDateObject.getTime() - myMinutes*60000); //Substracting your minutes variable
var dateHSubObject= new Date(oldDateObject.getTime() - myHours*60000); //Substracting your hours variable
```

To make it more managable you could do hours like this aswell for etc 24 hours

```
var myHours   = 60*24; // This represent 24 hours subtraction
```

You could also make the above code a function which wil take paramters like units, type and from that return your desired result

The 60000 part is milliseconds and represents 1 minute.

And welcome to StackOverflow, if you take some time exploring the website you will quickly be able to find the most common questions usually followed by great answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Without more knowledge I can't really give you an answer. 
But its likely that you're expecting a Date Object, when in reality your DB is returning something else.

(Maybe a string?, a number?)

Make sure what type of data is exactly storen in your "time" variable. Would be my suggestion because I dont see errors in the code. Must be the logic

Really hope this helped but more insight into what your DB is doing would help getting a clear answer :)

Good Luck !

Comment: It's a timestamp variable. It is stored as 9:30:00. I want to store this data as a javascript variable and pass is to date function in javascript. Later, I need to extract only hours and minutes from it and print as 9:30.

Comment: In JavaScript, a timestamp is the number of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970... Ive been working on a selfmade-calendar the past few months, so im kinda worked into the Date Object of Javascript. Ill' post it in a separate answer so other people can find it too ^^

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
let jsdate = new Date(unixtimestamp+1000);
```

example in use:

```
let a = new Date();
console.log("a ="+a)

let stamp = a.getTime()
console.log("stamp ="+stamp) // timestamp

let newTimeObj = new Date(stamp*1000)
console.log("newTimeObj :::::::"+newTimeObj)
```

OUTPUT::::

[image: Output]

Comment: if i was any help to anyone, i'd appretiate an upvote. Im still new here and im working really hard on getting some reputation points <3 !!

Comment: Just a hint. You do not have to concat results in the console as string. It is more simple to separate it. Like `console.log("a =", a)`.  This way you can actually investigate outputed objects instead of those being stringyfied. Also try to make a snippet out of the code so people can run it an see the result inline themselves. Lastly comment your steps.. like "why do I add 1000"?

Comment: Wow thank you I didnt know I could log results like that !

I thought what I posted was already a cnipped but I'm gonna look that up thank you so much for the feedback !

Also, yeah I see, people should understand what im doing since this is a helping plattform. 

Thanks so much for the feedback its VERY apreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the **UNIX Timestamp**(in seconds) which is coming from your `PHP` code to **milliseconds**, and then pass it as a **parameter** to a `Date object`.

Consider the below example in **JavaScript**:

```js
//UNIX Timestamp from your PHP code
let timeInUNIXTimeStamp = "1581653281"; 

// Create a new JavaScript Date object based on the timestamp
// Multiplied by 1000 to convert it into milliseconds, from seconds, as Date object works in milliseconds
var date = new Date(timeInUNIXTimeStamp * 1000);

// Get Hours part from the timestamp
var hours = date.getHours();

// Get Minutes part from the timestamp
var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();



// Will display time in H:M format
var timeInHMSFormat = hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2);

console.log(timeInHMSFormat);
```

You can same achieve in PHP also, there you need to convert UNIX Timestamp to H:M format, using the `date()` function, where the first parameter will the format you wanted and the second will be your `UNIX Timestamp`. 

Example: `date("h:i", 1581653281);` 
Where **h** is hours, in 12-hours format
            **i** is minutes

Read move about **PHP's** `data()` function  [Date function in php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Consider **PHP** the code below, inside your **JavaScript**:

```
   var time="<?php echo date('h:i', $row['time']); ?>";

   //Now Split the above string into array
   var timeArray = time.split(":");

   var hours = timeArray[0];
   var minutes = timeArray[1];
```

For more detail see this answer [Convert UNIX Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/847196/11926970)